# What does "One too many" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

In *The Departed (2006)*, Woman scolds Frank and Arnold for talking too much:

> Frank: Another county heard from.
>
> Arnold: **One too many**. She got a big mouth.

What does "One too many" mean ?

Comment: Can you give the time index when this dialogue happens?

Comment: It's not relevant to the question, but does he say "county" or "country"? "Another *country* heard from" is a set phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"One too many" is a shorter version of "[have] one too many", which generally means having had too many of something, not necessarily only one too many, but any number, so roughly, it's "too many" or "too often".

By far, the most common use of this phrase is about the amount of alcohol someone has consumed, and if the context doesn't indicate what there's too many of, it's understood to mean too many alcoholic beverages, which is the case here.

So in this context, it means:

> She has drunk too much alcohol.

Comment: I don't know *The Departed* so you may be right, but "one too many" doesn't refer *only* to one alcoholic drink too many.  *I've had one too many flats with these lightweight tubeless tires.  I'm taking them off my bike.*  or *You have cried wolf one too many times.*

Comment: @TimR Thanks for the catch. I've added that into my answer.

Comment: have one too many for booze, yes.